# 'Compile Error: User-defined type not defined' error shown after adding word object library through code

Tags: excel, vba

I am a newbie at VBA programming and this is my first post on a forum so I would like to apologise beforehand in case i make any mistakes.

I am automating an Excel workbook which opens and works with a new Word file from a template. I am using 'WithEvents' to track application events in Word. I am also using code to remove word object library references when closing the workbook and then adding them again at 'Workbook_Open' to make sure this workbook will work on other machines with different versions of word.

Everything works as expected except for a 'Compile Error: User-defined type not defined' error every time I open the workbook but consequent compilations work fine without a hitch. I know what is causing it - there is no reference to word object library during the first compile trial hence the compiler does not know what 'Word.Application' is but from the second instance onwards it does and hence produces no errors.

I just cannot ge my head around how to fix this. I have looked into LateBinding but from research I found out WithEvents is not compatible with LateBinding. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your time.

```
'ThisWorkbook'
'------------'

Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid GUID:="{00020905-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}", Major:=0, Minor:=0
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid GUID:="{00062FFF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}", Major:=0, Minor:=0

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    If IsEmpty(ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.Item("Word")) = False Then
        ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.Remove ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.Item("Word")
    End If

    If IsEmpty(ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.Item("Outlook")) = False Then
        ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.Remove ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.Item("Outlook")
    End If

    ActiveWorkbook.Save

    Set wdAppClass = Nothing
    Set wdAppClass.wdApp = Nothing
    'Set wdApp = Nothing
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set button = Nothing

End Sub
```

-

```
'Module1'
'-------'

Option Explicit

Public wdAppClass As New wdAppClass
Public wdDoc As Word.Document
Public button As Object
Public row As Integer
Public column As Integer

Public Sub AutoOpen()

    Set wdAppClass.wdApp = Word.Application

End Sub

Sub Button_Click()

    Set wdAppClass.wdApp = Word.Application
    Set button = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller)

    With button.TopLeftCell
        row = .row
        column = .column
    End With

    Set wdAppClass.wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set wdDoc = wdAppClass.wdApp.Documents.Add(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Sales Call Report.dotm")

    With wdDoc

        .Fields(3).Code.Text = " Quote " & """" & ActiveSheet.Range("A" & row & "").Text & """" & " "
        .Fields(4).Code.Text = " Quote " & """" & ActiveSheet.Range("B" & row & "").Text & """" & " "
        .Fields(5).Code.Text = " Quote " & """" & ActiveSheet.Range("C" & row & "").Text & """" & " "
        .Fields(6).Code.Text = " Quote " & """" & ActiveSheet.Range("D" & row & "").Text & """" & " "
        .Fields(7).Code.Text = " Quote " & """" & ActiveSheet.Range("E" & row & "").Text & """" & " "
        .Fields(8).Code.Text = " Quote " & """" & ActiveSheet.Range("H" & row & "").Text & """" & " "
        .Fields(9).Code.Text = " Quote " & """" & ActiveSheet.Range("J" & row & "").Text & """" & " "

        .Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ActiveSheet.Range("F" & row & "").Text
        .Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ActiveSheet.Range("K" & row & "").Text
        '.Shapes(3).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ActiveSheet.Range("M" & row & "").Text

    End With

    wdAppClass.wdApp.Selection.WholeStory
    wdAppClass.wdApp.Selection.Fields.Update
    wdAppClass.wdApp.Selection.Collapse

    wdAppClass.wdApp.Visible = True
    wdAppClass.wdApp.ActiveWindow.WindowState = wdWindowStateMaximize
    wdAppClass.wdApp.ActiveWindow.SetFocus
    wdAppClass.wdApp.Activate

End Sub

Sub Set_Reminder()

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem

    If button Is Nothing Then
        Set button = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller)
    End If

    With button.TopLeftCell
        row = .row
        column = .column
    End With

    On Error Resume Next

    Set olApp = GetObject("", "Outlook.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If olApp Is Nothing Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        On Error GoTo 0
        If olApp Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Outlook is not available!"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    Set olAppt = olApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

    With olAppt
        .Start = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("M" & row & "").Value & Chr(32) & Time()
        .Duration = 15
        .Subject = "Call " & ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("D" & row & "").Value
        .Location = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & row & "").Value & Chr(44) & Chr(32) & ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("C" & row & "").Value
        .Save
        .Display
    End With

    Set olApp = Nothing
    Set olAppt = Nothing
    Set button = Nothing

End Sub
```

-

```
'wdAppClass'
'----------'

Option Explicit

Public WithEvents wdApp As Word.Application

Private Sub wdApp_DocumentBeforeClose(ByVal Doc As Document, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim datecheck As Boolean

    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("F" & row & "").Value = wdDoc.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("K" & row & "").Value = wdDoc.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text

    datecheck = IsDate(wdDoc.Shapes(3).TextFrame.TextRange.Text)

    If datecheck = True Then
        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("M" & row & "").Value = wdDoc.Shapes(3).TextFrame.TextRange.Text
        Set_Reminder
    End If

    wdAppClass.wdApp.Quit
    wdApp.Quit
    wdDoc.Close

    Set wdAppClass = Nothing
    Set wdAppClass.wdApp = Nothing
    Set wdApp = Nothing
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set button = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Edited to include full code for the project. If anyone has some spare time, please feel free to test it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like Modules and Class Modules are compiled first when the Workbook is opened. Try using `Public WithEvents wdApp As Word.Application` within a Worksheet so it gets compiled after Workbook_Open.

Comment: Hello itsLex! Thank you for your quick response. It seems you are right about modules and class modules being compiled first and because of it when I tried your suggestion to put the public object declaration on a worksheet, it just proceeded on to marking the first line of the sub declaration in the class module with the same error. Any other suggestions?

Comment: If you insist on using the Word / Outlook items in a class, maybe you can define the entire class within one dedicated (very hidden) worksheet, for this purpose? Might work if you use only one instance.

Comment: Do you mean get rid of the wdappclass module completely? I apologise, I am afraid I am still getting my head around the handling of Classes and Class Modules. Would you mind elaborating a little bit more, maybe with an example or pseudo code etc. please?  Thank you!

Comment: Yes, get rid of both Module and Classmodule. But most of all, get rid of `Sub AutoOpen()`. That would require rewriting how your application works, I know. By keeping your code in a Worksheet, you can make calls like `Set Sheet9.wdApp = Word.Application`. Good luck.

Comment: itsLex thank you so much for your solution. Your ingenious idea of hiding the classmodule code in a worksheet worked a charm! Although I did remove both the module and classmodule, I had to reinstate the module as I needed some public variables and subs for it to work properly. I also learned from this exercise that worksheets and even the workbook itself cannot 'see' each others code even when public declarations are made. Thank you again!